# Silverligth 4 [Tabcontrol] - Double row op tabitems give a changing order

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend, tabcontrol

I am creating an interface that uses the silverligth tabControl. 
But i am bumping towards a problem in the order.

as you can see in the example this is the right order 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 (like you would read a book)

[image: right order]
.

but when clicking on the 'tab1' the order changes to this: 5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4

[image].

The people who work with the software find this very inconsistent, and dont understand why the order is changing. also because the tabs in JQueryUI does not have this problem.

Is there a method to freeze the tabs in the tabcontrol? so the tab1 stays where it supposed to stay in stead op moving with its row towards the bottem?

thanks,
Matthy

Comment: It's completly logical behavior, the upper row goes down because of focus, so the content can connect to the tab

Answer (score 1):

As Rumplin said, this is standard Windows behavior.  The options page in Word 2003 was infamous for it: [there were 3 rows of tabs](http://blogs.oracle.com/dancer/resource/tool_options.jpg).  If you're in a situation where you'll consistently have multiple rows of tabs, then a tab control is the wrong UI paradigm.  Contrast that Word 2003 options dialog with the [redesigned Word 2007 version.](http://www.projectwoman.com/uploaded_images/options-782303.jpg)  Tabs became the list of options on the left; selecting a "tab" populates the result view on the right.

I don't think there's a way to make the Silverlight tab control behave the way that you want.  Even if you could make it so, what would happen when the user clicks on tab1?  How would you visually link the content to the selected tab without moving the first row of tabs down?

You might find this helpful, particularly items 7 and 10: [13 design guidelines for tab controls](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/tabs.html).